# database data lost / mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I reformatted my pc and reinstalled my xampp installation but never overwritten the mysql folder (option in xampp install) and did not back up my database table thinking this is safe! (what was i thinking?)

Now, Myphpmyadmin shows there are tables exists-mydatabase(294)! but when clicking on shows mydatabase(0) tables - no tables found!!! running my drupal site gives me :

```
DOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydrupaldatabase.semaphore' doesn't exist: SELECT expire, value FROM {semaphore} WHERE name = :name; Array ( [:name] => variable_init ) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of F:\xampp\htdocs\mydrupalsite\includes\lock.inc)....
```

inside my mysql/data/mydrupaldatabase/ folder i can see there are all the *.frm files for my database. But I'm not sure if these are the actual data because there is only about 2mb worth of it when in fact i remember there should be around 4 mb of my data.

I strongly think my data is still there but phpmyadmin is probably just confused how to restore it.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First, verify that you have the correct `datadir` by using:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';
```

This should give you a directory that contains more directories based on the database names.  Inside each of these, you should see three types of files:

- `.frm` contains the table definition, but no actual data.
- `.myd` contains the raw table data. (MyISAM)
- `.myi` contains any table indices that you have defined. (MyISAM)
- `.ibd` contains the indices and data in a combined format. (InnoDB)

Here's where it gets tricky.  InnoDB (which you mentioned int he comments is what you're using) has the notion of tablespaces, much like Oracle.  That is, it separates the files out on the system into different namespaces if you've configured it to do; otherwise, it stores everything in the [system tablespace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/glossary.html#glos_system_tablespace).  Its typically in a file called `ibdata#`, where number can change.  If that's gone, then your data is gone.  Its very likely that your reinstall of MySQL backed up the file and put in the standard system file--but you'll need to look and see.

For future reference, you *can* create these on a per-file basis, which allows you to separate out the tablespaces into different files by using the [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) config option.

Comment: even if i am using innodb i should look for .myd files?

Comment: thanks for clarifying, i guess i have to learn this one the hard way. what i dont get is i never deleted any files during xampp re-install. this is a drupal-created database. but i can't see any more .myd files.

Comment: The default behavior for InnoDB is to store the files in the system tablespace; I've updated my answer to reflect that. (sorry for the ninja edit, @jnroche)!

Comment: innodb can also be in the "ibdata1" combined file in the datadir. And it is generally not considered a good idea to try and port innodb files between mysql servers unless they are definitely using the exact same version and config of mysql. BTW, with mysql "backup" is pronounced "mysqldump", anything else has gotchas attached.

Comment: oh yeah then i do have ibdata1 but it is not placed under the database folder name is this the one i need to recover? the file size makes sense to me about 18MB, it probably is also storing other database data since with the database concerned only has about 5MB of it! how do i proceed then?

Comment: @rackandboneman is correct, of course; this will not port between versions.  However, provided the names of the database and tables are the same, this should be possible.  This should NOT be inside of a database folder name, however.  [Somebody else has documented this exact situation with XAMPP](http://www.nerdydork.com/restoring-mysql-innodb-files-on-windows.html), though!

Comment: HOME is where ibdata1 is ;) So set your datadir to wherever it is, AFTER making a backup of the files there.